# Populate spinner with filenames saved on internal storage

Tags: android, local-storage, spinner

In my application I want to have a spinner that gets populated by the different files I saved to internal storage on this application. Following,

- I want to be able to open them from the spinner.
- I already created the spinner and was able to write and read the files to internal storage.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: can you show what you have tried..

Answer (score 0):

to list files from directory and to setup a spinner from the list:

```
String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();

//if you want to list from a specific directory you created
//String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString()+"/your_Directory";

File directory = new File(path);
File fileList[] = directory.listFiles();
String[] list = new String[fileList.size()];
String[] spinnerList = new String[fileList.size()];

for (int i=0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
    list[i] = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath().toString();
    spinnerList[i] = list[i].substring(list[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the code below, but now I would like to open the files into a TextView.
Right now I can only display the title of the file on the TextView, but I want to show the content of the file.
Thanks for your help!

```
public class ListasGravadas extends Activity {

    private TextView lista;
    private ListView listasGravadas;
    private Spinner spinner;

    String[] SavedFiles;
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listas_gravadas);

        lista = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        listasGravadas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ShowSavedFiles();

        addListenerToSpinner();

        FileInputStream fis;
        String content = "";
        try {
            String file = "teste";
            fis = openFileInput(file);
            byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
            }
            content += new String(input);

            lista.setText(content);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ShowSavedFiles();

    }

    private void ShowSavedFiles() {
        SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                SavedFiles);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addListenerToSpinner() {
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        lista = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {

                String result = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                lista.setText(result);


            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
void ShowSavedFiles() {
        SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                SavedFiles);


        listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```